# Amazon MWS API update stock without using feeds

Tags: amazon-mws

Currently, we are using the `SubmitFeed API` section (FeedType `_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_`) but because of the large number of SKUs (over 200k) we sometimes have problems to update our stock on time.  I wrote a sync job that determines inventory changes constantly and then, every 30 minutes, creates a new inventory feed, but is still not enough.

Do you know any alternative API Sections for SubmitFeed (`_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_`) or do you have an optimized solution for this without getting into throttling?

Answer (score 0):

The smallest and, thus, quickest feed to send is

```
_POST_FLAT_FILE_PRICEANDQUANTITYONLY_UPDATE_DATA_
```

It's basically a CSV file with sku, new stock and new price. Amazon handles it in a reasonable short while. We handle about 120k SKUs and send a full hourly update with no issues.